# Flea Dust or Skin Issue?

Tags: cats, skin-condition, fleas

I am going to switch vets on Thursday as I don't feel like my cat is getting the right attention. He has a bump on his head the vet didn't even look at really. Gave me topical ointment for a week that did nothing-- then gave me oral medicine to try for 2 weeks again without looking at the bump.

Now I'm finding this orange looking dust on Kitty on his right thigh. I tried googling and came up with flea dust, but there seems to be no blood. Is this just some sort of dermatitis? Dirt? Can it be from the antibiotics? I found a well reviewed vet, but I can't see them till Thursday. And I just keep thinking, what more can go wrong for the poor small one?

Also to note: his behavior hasn't changed, he's not licking or scratching the area. I only noticed it when holding him to give him his antibiotics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has he been acting unusual or scratching a lot? I would try bathing with either cat (flea) shampoo or dawn soap and look for 2 things: 1) do fleas come jumping off with the soap (they will) or are floating in the water, or 2) is it gone with no fleas in the water? Sometimes cats just need a bath, especially if they are older or have trouble grooming.